# Droppable event occasionally not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable, droppable

For drag and drop functionality I am using jquery-1.12.4.js and jquery-ui.js. When I am using the `droppable` function of this it is some times working and some times not. This is my javascript code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".connectedSortable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log("event--", event);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my full code:  http://jsfiddle.net/vgmz6qnj/1/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work fine. I dragged everything around and had no issues at all. Please give more information about it 'sometimes not working'. Check the console when these problems happen

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please try two three time some time its work and some time not

Comment: I have done. I've moved each item so that they're all within in each container and back out again and have had no issues at all. Have you checked the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://www.screencast.com/t/HYwIptdCQp please check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated problem boils down to the fact that this listener:

```
$(".connectedSortable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log("event--", event);
  }
});
```

**Does not fire consistently (as shown in the posted by OP video).**

My thinking is that this is due to the droppable area fluctuating in size. What I did just to test/demonstrate my theory was to make that area height `100%` and with that I was not able to see a miss-fire of the droppable listener.

> [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akrion/vgmz6qnj/20/)

Note the changes:

1. Added some CSS to make the body/html/table height 100% in order to have unlimited horizontal drop area.
2. Added a class to the table called `tableContainer`.

Please correct me if I am wrong on my assumptions.